# Ajax not returning desired results or not working at all

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to load return a JsonResults action from a controller in MVC using ajax call. I can see that the alert() function is triggering well but the ajax is not executing. I have search for several sources but to no avail.

```
public JsonResult FillBusinessLicenceL3(int? selectedID)
    {
        var bl3_Items = db.LevelThreeItems.Where(l3 => l3.LevelTwoItem_ID == selectedID);

        return Json(bl3_Items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The below too is the javascript calling for the json method.

```
<script>
function FillBussLicence_L3items() {
    alert("You have clicked me");
    var bl2_Id = $('#BussLicenceL2_ID').val();
    //alert(document.getElementById("BussLicenceL2_ID").value);
    alert(bl2_Id);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'StartSurvey/FillBusinessLicenceL3/' + bl2_Id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: "{}", // { selectedID : bl2_Id },
        //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (bussLicence_L3items) {
            $("#BussLicenceL3_ID").html(""); // clear before appending new list
            $.each(bussLicence_L3items, function (i, licenceL3) {
                $("#BussLicenceL3_ID").append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(licenceL3.LevelThreeItem_ID).html(licenceL3.LevelThreeItem_Name));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Also, I have tried this one too but no execution notice.
Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: Open the browser's console. Look for any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the browser's console, I noticed that the LINQ query was tracking the database and was creating a circular reference so I changed the query to the following and voila!!

```
public JsonResult FillBusinessLicenceL3(int? selectedID)
    {
        var bl3_Items = db.LevelThreeItems.
            Where(k => k.LevelTwoItem_ID == selectedID).
            Select(s => new { LevelThreeItem_ID = s.LevelThreeItem_ID, LevelThreeItem_Name = s.LevelThreeItem_Name });

        return Json(bl3_Items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

There was nothing wrong with the ajax call to the controller.